# Imagens desaparecem em slider Safari?

Tags: css, safari

O site é www.gogogostore.pt .

As imagens cortam e em mobile fica tudo cortado.

Não sei se será um problema de CSS mas é isto:

```
/** ROLETA **/

.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  position:static;
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.wrapper1 {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  margin:5px auto 5px 0;
}


.carousel{
   width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
  padding-top: 55%;
}

.inner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
      margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}




.slide{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide.active,
.slide.left,
.slide.right{
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}



.js-reset-left{left:auto}


.slide.left{
  left:-100%;
  right:0;
}

.cash {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.slide.right{
  right:-100%;
  left: auto;
}

.transition .slide.left{left:0%}
.transition .slide.right{right:0%}


.transition .slide.shift-right{right: 100%;left:auto}
.transition .slide.shift-left{left: 100%;right:auto}


.transition .slide{
  transition-property: right, left, margin;
}

/**
 * ==========================
 * Indicators
 *
 */
.indicators{
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 4;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.indicators li{
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.indicators li.active{background:#909090}

.indicators li:hover{background-color:#909090}

/**
 * ==========================
 * Arrows 
 *
 */
.arrow{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  z-index: -2;
  border-top:3px solid #fff;
  border-right:3px solid #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:border-color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.arrow:hover{border-color:#909090}

.arrow-left{
  left:20px;
  transform:rotate(225deg);
    z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-right{
  right:20px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 2;
}



 */
.slide{
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:60%;
  background-size:cover;
}

.displayprod {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(1){
  background-image:url(/assets/images/slidegogogo.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
 }

.slide:nth-child(2){
  background-image:url(/assets/images/slide2gogogo.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}

.slide:nth-child(3){
  background-image:url(/assets/images/slide3gogogo.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:auto 1000px;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

o HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="inner">
<a href="{{ site.url }}/tshirts" class="slide active"><p class="newcl" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin !important;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 30px;justify-content: center;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">NEW COLLECTION</p><br><p class="bottext" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 60px;justify-content: center;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">T-SHIRTS SS19</p></a>
<a href="{{ site.url }}/camisas" class="slide">
  <p class="newcl" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 30px;justify-content: center;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">NEW COLLECTION</p>
<p class="bottext" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 60px;justify-content: center;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">SHIRTS SS19</p></a>
    <a href="{{ site.url }}/camisas" class="slide">
  <p class="newcl" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin !important;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 30px;justify-content: center;">NEW COLLECTION</p>
<p class="bottext" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;font-size: 60px;justify-content: center;">SUMMER VIBES</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow arrow-left"></div>
    <div class="arrow arrow-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alguem me ajude pf :(

Comment: Cara só o CSS não ajuda muito, edita a pergunta e coloca tb o HTML

Comment: coloquei o HTML se poder ajudar responda pf

Comment: Pedro na verdade o html eh pra ver ser ajuda alguém a te responder, mas eu não tenho mac aqui para testar no safari, então não tenho como testar corretamente... Reparei que no CSS vc declara do top: nos elementos, mas não declara o left, tente colocar left:0 neles para ver se resolve

Comment: tentei e nao funcionou. mas obrigado na mesma.